# Cannot read properties of undefined trim()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

El metodo de trim no me lo detecta como función, no me lo detecta.

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();

const onSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    if( inputValue.trim().length <= 1) return;

    setCategories( (categories) =>  [inputValue, ...categories])
  }
```

Tengo esta función donde al momento de hacer click en la tecla enter, se tiene que mandar una cadena de texto a una lista que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en que el tipo de dato de inputValue es undefined. El metodo trim() funciona para un tipo de dato string.
Intenta inicializar el useState con un string vacio:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(''); // Inicializando con un string vacio
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta!!!